# Knockout.js binding radio group does not work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I feel really stupid but can't make it work :)

http://jsfiddle.net/btkmR/

I made this simple Fiddle just to prove that I'm not missing something in my big project.

HTML:

```
<div>
    Preferred flavor
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" data-bind="checked: cherryOn" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" data-bind="checked: almondOn" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" data-bind="checked: mgOn" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    cherryOn: ko.observable(true);
    almondOn: ko.observable(false);
    mgOn: ko.observable(false);
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I expect to see `Cherry` selected on start..

Comment: In addition to Jeremy's answer, your fiddle isn't referencing Knockout, and your viewmodel definition is illegal. When using the object literal notation, you use comma's, not semi-colons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Knockout's documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only
>   if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/btkmR/2/

```
<div>
    Preferred flavor
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: flavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond"  data-bind="checked: flavor" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="Monosodium"  data-bind="checked: flavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>

var viewModel = {
    flavor: ko.observable("cherry")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I was thinking it's boolean. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 13):

For those who, like me, are struggling to get it working with **dynamically bound radio group name and values**, pay attention to order of bindings in the `data-bind`.

Following will NOT work, as `value` and `name` are bound *after* `checked`:

```
<input 
    type="radio" 
    data-bind="
        checked: $parent.correctAnswerId, 
        attr: {name: 'correctAnswerFor' + $parent.id, value: id}
    "
/>
```

**correct** order is :

```
        attr: {name: 'correctAnswerFor' + $parent.id, value: id},
        checked: $parent.correctAnswerId
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very interesting issue as well. If your radio input values are numbers and you have integers in your model observables - no radio button will get selected. If you update observable value to be "1" (number as string), then it works. Not very convenient...